# Relation between rank of tensor and electromechanical property of a material

Tags: tensor-calculus, crystals, piezoelectric

In piezoelectricity, the piezoelectric tensor is of rank three and its a reason why piezoelectricity is not present in all materials whereas for electrostriction, it is present for all crystal symmetries because the electrostriction tensor is of rank four.

So, I think the presence of the electromechanical phenomenon is related to the rank of the related tensor because the rank is related to the crystal structure ?

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: Applications of material symmetry and point group analysis lie outside my research focus, and so I'm relying on class-gained background knowledge here along with a textbook survey to at least provide pointers for further study. I hope you'll let me know if anything's unclear so that this answer can be improved.)

> So, I think the presence of the electromechanical phenomenon is related to the rank of the related tensor **because the rank is related to the crystal structure** ? [emphasis added]

I think it's important to emphasize that the rank is not related to the crystal structure. The rank depends on which driving forces and resulting "displacements" are linked in the phenomenon of interest, and we might investigate this phenomenon—or its absence—in any crystal structure with any symmetry class.

For example, so-called direct piezoelectricity couples the polarization (a first-order tensor) with stress (a second-order tensor that itself couples a force with an area normal vector, both first-order tensors) and is thus described by a third-order tensor.

Converse piezoelectricity couples the electric field (a first-order tensor) with strain (a second-order tensor that itself couples linear features in undeformed and deformed regions, both first-order tensors) and is also thus described by a third-order tensor.

Electrostriction couples an electrostatic aspect (electric field or polarization) quadratically with strain and is thus described by a fourth-order tensor. (I would like to find a more physical and intuitive explanation here than just saying "quadratically.")

Some other third-rank material property tensors are the ones associated with piezomagnetism and the Pockels (electrooptic) effect, so we might use these as intuitive test cases—backed up by the underlying math of tensor symmetry analysis—to test whether
a certain characteristic is specific to piezoelectricity or is generally implied by a rank-three tensor. As you note, the characteristic of interest here is absence in the case of certain crystal symmetry.

Hertel in *Continuum Physics* notes that "If the crystal has an inversion center...there can be no proper tensor of rank three." The broad intuitive explanation here is that if an effect's direction is reversed upon mirror reflection, and the material exhibits mirror symmetry, then the effect can't exist in that particular material, as Nature can't distinguish between an original configuration—in which the effect points in a certain direction—and the (identical) mirrored configuration—in which the effect should point in the opposite direction but simultaneously shouldn't. A proof is given in §8.2 of Newnham's *[Properties of Materials: Anisotropy, Symmetry, Structure](https://www.xray.cz/kryst/fyzikalni_krystalografie_b.pdf)*. Table  12.2 gives a list of all point groups for which the piezoelectric tensor is identically zero.

Narasimhamurty in *Photoelastic and Electro-Optic Properties of Crystals* proves the special case that for crystals with symmetry class 432 (not necessarily containing an inversion center), all elements of a third-rank tensor are zero. This and related points are discussed in Ballato's "[Piezoelectricity: Old Effect, New Thrusts](https://zenodo.org/record/1262081/files/article.pdf)." Kholkin, Pertsev, and Goltsev note in "[Piezoelectricity and crystal symmetry](https://medien.ubitweb.de/pdfzentrale/978/038/776/Leseprobe_9780387765389_Sonstige_Informationen_01.PDF)" in *Piezoelectric and Acoustic Materials for Transducer Applications* that "In the...21 noncentrosymmetric crystallographic classes...piezoelectricity may exist, except for the cubic class 432, where the piezoelectric charges developed along the 111 polar axes cancel each other."

I hope this survey helps clarify the relationship between certain phenomena and the crystal (a)symmetries through which they can and cannot arise.